# C#: Unhandled Exceptions when Converting from String to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, exception

I am attempting to write a simple GUI application that will load customer data from the Customer class when the retrieve button is clicked.  This data is then stored in a Customer object when the save button is clicked.

I found through testing that my clear and retrieve buttons work as expected, but I receive the following error message when I press the save button:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.  If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.  If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  There is an unknown word starting at index 4.

I have pasted my code below.  I would appreciate any clarification you all could provide.  Thank you in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace simple_GUI
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Customer myCustomer = new Customer(); //Declare an instance of the customer class within my Windows form

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCustomer.Id = Convert.ToInt32(customerIDTextBox.Text); //How to handle exceptions within my conversions?
            myCustomer.Name = fullNameTextBox.Text;
            myCustomer.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
            myCustomer.Email = emailTextBox.Text;
            myCustomer.Phone = Convert.ToDouble(phoneNumberTextBox.Text);
            myCustomer.AddDate = Convert.ToDateTime(addressTextBox.Text);
            myCustomer.TotalTransactions = Convert.ToInt32(totalTransactionsTextBox.Text);


        }

        private void retrieveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerIDTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myCustomer.Id); 
            fullNameTextBox.Text = myCustomer.Name;
            addressTextBox.Text = myCustomer.Address;
            emailTextBox.Text = myCustomer.Email;
            phoneNumberTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myCustomer.Phone);
            addDateTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myCustomer.AddDate);
            totalTransactionsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(myCustomer.TotalTransactions);

        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerIDTextBox.Text = "";
            fullNameTextBox.Text = "";
            addressTextBox.Text = "";
            emailTextBox.Text = "";
            phoneNumberTextBox.Text = "";
            addDateTextBox.Text = "";
            totalTransactionsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(""); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the text of addressTextBox(maybe this is the key:convert the address string to datetime)? The error is very clear: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: And I suggest you use DateTimePicker control to let user input date rather than textbox

Comment: what format are you using for your date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check ifit is possible to convert before set the value converting directly, using `TryParse()` methods of the types, you could take a right conversion, try something like this

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if the Id is a integer
    int convertedId;
    if (!int.TryParse(customerIDTextBox.Text, out convertedId))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The ID is not a integer value");
        return;
    }

    myCustomer.Id = convertedId;
    myCustomer.Name = fullNameTextBox.Text;
    myCustomer.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
    myCustomer.Email = emailTextBox.Text;
    myCustomer.Phone = phoneNumberTextBox.Text;

    // check if the DateTime is a valid dateTeime
    DateTime convertedDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(addressTextBox.Text,"MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out convertedDate))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The filed is not a valid date");
        return;
    }

    myCustomer.AddDate = convertedDate;


    myCustomer.TotalTransactions = Convert.ToInt32(totalTransactionsTextBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a cast and do something if it does not work?

```
private bool ValidInteger(string value)
{
    int notUsed=0;
    return Int32.TryParse(value, out notUsed);
}
```

I removed the function keyword. The code now compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You may validate the input by adding some codes, take AddDate for example:

```
try{
   myCustomer.AddDate = Convert.ToDateTime(addressTextBox.Text);
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Add Date is not valid");
   return;
}
```

and if possible, use the DatePicker control for inputting a date.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use proper naming on your text boxes. Your code shows that when you save your date, you're using your addressTextBox.Text:

```
myCustomer.AddDate = Convert.ToDateTime(addressTextBox.Text);
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
myCustomer.AddDate = DateTime.Parse(dateTextBox.Text,"MM/dd/yyyy");
```

It also better to use DateTimePicker control rather than a TextBox when a user is selecting dates. Hope this helps!